# Getting error "Payment Required" on IBM Cloudant NoSQL DB

Tags: api, error-handling, ibm-cloud, cloudant

I am using the Lite plan of IBM Cloudant NOSQL DB service. I have a database with 100k+ JSON documents which is around 250 MB in size.

When I try to hit the GET /_all_docs API through Postman, I get an error with HTTP statusCode 402.

```
{
    "error": "payment_required",
    "reason": "Payment required"
}
```

This probably means some feature not available in the Lite Plan is being used.
However, I am only using the GET /_all_docs API to retrieve documents from the Database. It was working earlier but now suddenly I have started getting this error.

What does it mean? Could not find anything in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

On a Lite plan you'd get 402 if and only if your total data volume exceeds the 1G cap - so that's data + indexes. Contact support to verify.

The Lite plan (and the Standard plan, too) is also rate limited - but such transgressions would give rise to a "429: Too Many Requests" error, not a 402.

Comment: My data volume was just around 250 MB, I did not exceed the 1 GB cap on the Lite Plan.

Comment: If you got a 402, you exceeded your data volume cap. Without knowing your account name, I can't check; open a support case for more detailed analysis. Note, however, that the data volume cap includes indexes -- if you use any views over your 250Mb, it is perfectly possibly that this pushes you over the limit.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the terms for the [Cloudant Lite plan](https://console.bluemix.net/catalog/services/cloudant). In addition to the [storage limits, there are also limits on the supported query rate](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/Cloudant/offerings/bluemix.html#ibm-cloud-public). Lookups, writes and queries are capped. Likely that you ran into them.

The [402 status code](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/Cloudant/offerings/bluemix.html#request-and-document-size-limits) is documented for such cases.

Comment: Thank you. My data was just about 250 MB in size and I did not make more than 10 write queries per second. Made sure the plan limits weren't exceeded.